# bitbucket - git push,clone,pull got error 500

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, http-status-code-500

my git server is on standalone network. Yesterday I increased my server space and after that I didn't have any access to the files in bitbucket.

I can't do push, clone, pull... nothing.

When I click on any repository on bit bucket I got error 500, as you can see on the picture.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

[image: The error I got in bitbucket]

Answer (score 2):

Error 500 means an error on the server side.

You need to [inspect your BitBucket server logs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-debug-logging-776640147.html), assuming you have activated said logs in  `<Bitbucket home directory>/shared/bitbucket.properties`

```
logging.logger.ROOT=DEBUG
logging.logger.com.atlassian.bitbucket=DEBUG
```

Or, at runtime:

```
curl -u <ADMIN_USERNAME> -v -X PUT -d "" -H "Content-Type: application/json" <BASE_URL>/rest/api/latest/logs/rootLogger/debug
curl -u <ADMIN_USERNAME> -v -X PUT -d "" -H "Content-Type: application/json" <BASE_URL>/rest/api/latest/logs/logger/com.atlassian.bitbucket/debug
```

Then you can see what is going on when you try and access that repository.